# Duplicate image with touch

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, touchesbegan

Im trying to duplicate an image in Swift 4 when the user touches  the screen

```
var positionArray = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 2), count: 50)
var counter = 0
var pointNum = 0
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: self.view)
        let locx = Int(position.x)
        let locy = Int(position.y)
            positionArray[counter] = [locx, locy]
            print(positionArray[counter])
            counter = counter + 1
            point.center = position
            pointNum = pointNum + 1
    }
}
```

As you can see this is what I use to register touch, but I only have a single image (point) that moves to where the user touches.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the intended outcome. Do you want to duplicate the whole image when  the user touches anywhere on the screen? because right now, you are saving the array of points on touches began. there's no code to duplicate the image.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm trying to do: I only have 1 image in a certain location, I want the same image to appear where the user touched without eliminating the first one

Answer (score 0):

Your code saves your points to an array of points, and then moves the center of something called `point`. Is `point` an image view?

If you want to create a new copy of an image everywhere the user taps then you need to create a new copy of the image. Something like this:

```
let bounds = point.bounds
let newImageView = UIImageView(frame: bounds)
newImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
newImageView.image = UIImage(named: "MyImageViewName")
self.view.addSubView(newImageView)
newImageView.center = position
```

Note that it would really be better to add auto layout anchors that anchor the new image view's center to the superview's origin, but the above code *should* work. (I think. I've rarely used `newImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`.)

Comment: point IS a image view. Thanks for the response. Will try immediately!

Comment: Hey, is there a way to use `self.view.addSubView(newImageView)` in a UIViewController?, or I'm I limited to a UIView?

Comment: That code is written assuming it would be run from a view controller. For a view controller, self.view is the view controller's content view.